# How to view/read the db2 logs? Is there any way to read db2 logs in normal text format?

Tags: db2

Is there any other ways(Such as tools) than C, C++ APIs to view or export binary format logs in normal readable format?

If tools are available, please provide download links.

Thanks in advance.

I am using DB2 V11.5 on windows (Server Edition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one: [DB2 Recovery Expert for Linux, UNIX and Windows](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/im/db2recovery/index.html)

Comment: Hi @Mark, I tried this but I could see only summary reports, Is there any chance for viewing raw logs in UTF-8 format or any readable formats ?

Comment: [Log Analysis](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS8QJD_5.5.0/db2re_v5r5/contents/amacloganalysis.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help :).. I am using db2 in windows. Is there any way to write the ddl/dml auditing logs as system logs(Windows Application Events) like MSSQL ddl dml auditing.?

Comment: You need custom scripting for this.

Comment: Any Tutorials or examples for this..?

Comment: Please, open a new question and be more specific on what you want audit exactly.

Comment: Please Refer- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57818297/how-to-write-db2-ddl-dml-audit-logs-as-system-application-logs?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000