# How to write DB2 DDL & DML audit logs as System Application Logs?

Tags: db2, ddl, db2-luw, dml, auditing

I am using DB2 LUW in a windows machine. I want to get the logs for DDL & DML queries used in the database.

The default logs(for example S000001.LOG) contains 'null' and not in a readable format. So I enabled auditing and extracted the archived audit logs into .del files.

But the audit log extraction creates .del like this:

### execute.del

`"2019-09-05-01.19.44.443001","EXECUTE","STATEMENT",13,0,"TEST2","Administrator","ADMINISTRATOR","ADMINISTRATOR",,,"*LOCAL.DB2.190904193137","db2bp.exe",,,,,,,,"ADMINISTRATOR","SQLC2O29",203,,"      ","                    ",10,1,0,0,"WRITE_DML","auditlobs.0.42/","CS","auditlobs.42.808/",1,0,,,,,,"2019-09-05-01.19.44.178765",,"DB2","DESKTOP-R9O62O0"`

**the empty spaces are like NULNULNUL while opening the file in notepad++**

### auditlob.file

`insert into db2admin.testtable values(223)GEN_CMPL      (                        DD                               (  ¸        0  ¸        8  ¸        @  ¸        H  ¸           P  ¸

      X  ¸`

**This file contains characters like STX NUL EOX US... etc**

In my case either I should get the logs in any readable format(Like db2diag.log file) or I have to forward the logs to a syslog server in a standard format.

What is the best way to do it?

Is there any possibility to write the audit logs as System Application Events Like MSSQL DDL/DML Auditing? so that I could easily forward those logs.

auditlobs.file and execute.del -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/vapyB.jpg

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These CSV files may be [imported](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008304.html) or [loaded](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html) into Db2 tables for further analysis / processing.
You may use any other tools with an ability to process CSV files and log their contents to whatever system.

Comment: While loading  field "auditlobs.0.42/" with "lobs from" command, I got this result -> https://imgur.com/a/X0xygYL     I need the statement in a readable format.!

Comment: The auditlobs file and execute.del file looks like this -> https://imgur.com/a/9LydhYK

Comment: @Selva Refer to the following link: [Loading Db2 audit data into tables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.sec.doc/doc/t0011543.html). You must use `MODIFIED BY DELPRIORITYCHAR LOBSINFILE` clause for `IMPORT` / `LOAD`.